# How do I access this object property without foreach loop

Tags: php, moodle

How can I access the value overall_score without doing a foreach each loop?

I'm trying get the value overall score, I tried `$links->overall_score` but I get:

> Notice: Undefined property: mysqli_native_moodle_recordset::$overall_score in
>   /Users/richard/Sites/moodle/moodle/report/link_critic/link_detail.php
>   on line 90

So I'm doing

```
$links = $DB->get_recordset_sql($query_links);
```

here's the object I get back from my query

```
mysqli_native_moodle_recordset Object
(
[result:protected] => mysqli_result Object
    (
        [current_field] => 0
        [field_count] => 17
        [lengths] => Array
            (
                [0] => 4
                [1] => 4
                [2] => 2
                [3] => 1
                [4] => 10
                [5] => 24
                [6] => 18
                [7] => 1
                [8] => 0
                [9] => 29
                [10] => 5
                [11] => 4
                [12] => 1
                [13] => 1
                [14] => 0
                [15] => 10
                [16] => 1
            )

        [num_rows] => 21
        [type] => 0
    )

[current:protected] => Array
    (
        [id] => 17397
        [resource_id] => 2512
        [page_id] => 15
        [user_id] => 1
        [link_submitted] => 1462649904
        [link_title] => Cold Spring Harbour page
        [link_description] => A useful brain map
        [link_status] => 1
        [link_broken] => 
        [link_url] => http://www.g2conline.org/2022
        [link_id] => 1583
        [vote_score] => 1
        [vote_comment] => 
        [vote_timestamp] => 1464795526
        [overall_score] => 1
    )

)
```

A Var Dump of $links->current()

```
object(stdClass)#4476 (15) { ["id"]=> string(5) "17397" ["resource_id"]=> string(4) "2512" ["page_id"]=> string(2) "15" ["user_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["link_submitted"]=> string(10) "1462649904" ["link_title"]=> string(24) "Cold Spring Harbour page" ["link_description"]=> string(18) "A useful brain map" ["link_status"]=> string(1) "1" ["link_broken"]=> NULL ["link_url"]=> string(29) "http://www.g2conline.org/2022" ["link_id"]=> string(4) "1583" ["vote_score"]=> string(1) "1" ["vote_comment"]=> NULL ["vote_timestamp"]=> string(10) "1464795526" ["overall_score"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

Comment: A guess after a quick google search, `$links->current()['overall_score']`? (Depending on PHP version).

Comment: It looks like it's got a couple arrays. Try `$links->current["overall_score"]`

Comment: @JeffPuckettII $links is an object by the looks of it, and the `current` property is protected.

Comment: @JonStirling I get 
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /Users/richard/Sites/moodle/moodle/report/link_critic/link_detail.php on line 90 when I try your idea

Comment: @JeffPuckettII I get cannot access protected property...

Comment: @Rich Can you `var_dump($links->current())` please?

Comment: In Moodle, the `get_recordset_xxx` methods were created so you can fetch a large dataset without loading the whole thing into memory. i.e., you need to iterate over the dataset to view all the data. If you're only going to be returning one record, why not use `get_records_sql` which returns the data directly?

Comment: I'm returning more than one record , but yes that's the way to do it for one. @JonStirling I will post the var_dump in the question

Comment: based on @dleiftah suggestion, change your $query_links variable to SELECT overall_score instead of SELECT *

Comment: @Rich Right, so it's `$links->current()->overall_score`. I will restate though, I've not used moodle, and others may have the "proper" solution.

Comment: If those values are all protected, then there must be some getter/setter methods implemented in the class. Query the available methods with `get_class_methods()`. Also, **accessible** properties of an initialized object can be listed with `get_object_vars()`.

Comment: @JonStirling yep that's it. Just needed to figure it out for now, I can see there are some other 'proper' solutions for me to dive into too. Thank you everyone .

Answer (score 0):

Recordset returns multiple records.

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API#Using_Recordsets

So, assuming overall_score is a column in the sql, you should use :

```
$links = $DB->get_recordset_sql($query_links);
foreach ($links as $link) {
    echo $link->overall_score;
}
$links->close(); // This bit is very important!!!
```

If you are only expecting a single record then use `get_record_sql()`

```
$link = $DB->get_record_sql($query_links);
echo $link->overall_score;
```

If you are new to Moodle, then maybe keep this pinned in your browser for reference:

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API